# XMLHttpRequest cannot load from localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I use a ajax that looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'webapi/this is web api url',
            type: 'GET',
            data: '',

            success: function(data) {
                  //called when successful
                  console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                  //called when there is an error
                  console.log(e.message);
            }
          });
```

And with that I want to make a get request on another domain, from my codeigniter project on localhost(I will move that a on server later on). Another thing is that I cannot have access to that API(since is not mine) where I send my GET to edit any code.

Now the problem that I get is this error on the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'webapi/this is web api url' . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost blabla' is therefore not allowed access.

The things in the ' ' are the placeholders for my actual URL's. So it's clear to me that the domain where I try to send a GET isn't allowing my 3rd party app on localhost (although I read in their API documentation that they accept...)

I saw some outdated topics on stackoverflow about that, but I hope there is a better way to bypass that, what I try'ed:

- `dataType: "jsonp",` with that I will got:

> Refused to execute script from 'webapi/this is web api url' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

- I passed in the head ('text/plain'), didn't work
- with [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)
- with Korz

None of that worked, there were some methods, that are quite risky due to cross site scripting that I cannot consider.
Only thing that worked but isn't unreliable is the chrome plugin called Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *, but that is only for testing on my browser,  but I will move this to a public site.
Any good solutions, thank you so much for your time!

Comment: When making a request the receiving domain must be *exactly* the same as the requester, down to the protocol and port. If this isn't the case the request will be treated as cross-domain and a whole manner of security restrictions are put in place. To fix the error: either make the request to the same domain, or if that's not possible, add a CORS header to the response. If you can do neither of those, then you will not be able to make the request in JS and will have to do it server-side instead

Comment: `isn't allowing my 3rd party app on localhost` ... to be clear, the page is on `localhost` and `webapi` is some other domain, that you believe does allow "CORS" - check in the developer tools network tab, check the response headers for proper CORS repsonse headers. If they are not present, then the 3rd party either doesn't allow CORS at all, or, perhaps doesn't allow CORS from `localhost`

Comment: @JaromandaX I got in the response head: Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Date:Wed, 01 Feb 2017 12:29:24 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=20
P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:id=Ih5s7Auq93eGc14B0MPN470355;expires=Wed, 08-Feb-2017 12:29:24 GMT;path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Comment: Right, so no CORS headers received - so your problem is that the server doesn't want your `localhost`ed page accessing its resources